# "Stor" é realmente o termo mais comum para "professor" em Portugal?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, vocabulário, gíria

Ao me deparar com a seguinte imagem<sup>*</sup>:

[image: Maneira Mais Comum de se Referir a Professor escolar em Portugal: stor.]

que afirma que

> Maneira Mais Comum de se Referir a Professor (de Escola)
> Portugal: **stor**
> *stor* é uma abreviação de "senhor doutor"

de início imaginei que havia um erro quanto a Portugal, afinal jamais tinha encontrado a palavra "stor" e os primeiros dicionários que cheguei não continham a palavra. Contudo ela consta na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/stor) e em outros [sites](https://falarportugues.net/giria-da-escola-em-portugues/), então sei que existe.

O que ainda não me parece claro:

1. "Stor" é realmente a maneira mais comum de se dirigir/referir a professores em Portugal?
2. Ela é pronunciada exatamente como é escrita (ou como "istor" ou "sitor", "shtor", etc.)?

<sub>* Fonte da imagem: https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/14rcekr/most_common_way_to_address_a_high_school_teacher</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Portugal é muito comum ouvir jovens chamando professores de "stor"! Na escola e na faculdade (porém, neste último caso apenas quando falam sobre o professor e não os chamam assim quando falam com eles).

A pronúncia é com o [s] mesmo, não "chiado" e sem a inserção de uma vogal antes.

É interessante que no Brasil, além do "profe", ouve-se hoje em dia "sor", forma curta de só "professor".

Comment: Há muito tempo que deixei os bancos escolares, mas nunca soube que os alunos brasileiros usam "sor" ou "profe".

Comment: @Centaurus Também já ouvi, penso que inclusive variações como "psor" ou "prófi".

Comment: @stafusa E é provável que um professor ouça diversas variações.  Adolescentes sentem-se importantes ao criar termos que são adotados por seus pares.  Acredito que isso seja bem raro em uma turma de adultos.

Comment: @Centaurus Bem, "adultos" calouros na universidade acabaram de sair da escola. Pelo que me lembro, se dirigir a um professor com um "profe" é mesmo raro, mas se referir a ele dessa forma entre pares, não. Mas esse tipo de vocabulário coloquial depende muito da região - no Paraná e em São Paulo pode ser bem diferente do Rio.

Comment: @stafusa  Idioletos.